# Setters in generic xaml that modifies named component properties inside a ribbon control

Tags: wpf, ribboncontrolslibrary

I was asking in 
[16x16 pixel images in RibbonApplicationMenuItem gets stretched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898118/16x16-pixel-images-in-ribbonapplicationmenuitem-gets-stretched/11902118#11902118) how to make images that are in ribbon menu items smaller (and not stretching out to 32x32 as if that in any case would be desirable).

I got an excellent answer, based on replacing the control template for such controls and then I started to think that I could instead use the already present templates and have setters in generic.xaml that modifies properties in them.

How to see which component structure a ribbon control has? It is easily done by right clicking the property "Template" and extract the control template to an existing xaml file.

I could investigate the whole component structure of such a menu item. Here and where, there are named components, and I found a component with the name "Image".

So I tried to do this in generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem}">
  <Setter Property="Image.Height" Value="16" />
  <Setter Property="Image.Width" Value="16" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonApplicationSplitMenuItem}">
  <Setter Property="Image.Height" Value="16" />
  <Setter Property="Image.Width" Value="16" />
</Style>
```

but all I got was this:

[image]

Well, it had some effect, but what is really happening?
What did I do wrong? Can I resize named images of a control like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this is what I have got while researching:

```
<Setter Property="Image.Height" Value="16" />
```

is setting the height of any instance of Image, not the control with the Name "Image".

And using

```
<Setter TargetName="Image" Property="Height" Value="16" />
```

does not work because you cant use TargetName inside a template, unless its in a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I ve never tried something like this with themes in generic.xaml but you can create a new file and create a new resourcedictionary. Now insert your styles and set the x:Key attribute like this: x:Key{x:Type ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem}. Now go to your App.xaml and it should look like this

```
<Application x:Class="Coba.WPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"              
             StartupUri="MainPage.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                                   <ResourceDictionarySource="yourresourcedictionarypath.xaml" />

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>           
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```